# Identify LEGO Dimensions pack

Tags: set-identification, lego-dimensions

Can you please help me figure out which character this build pack goes with?

The bag has a copyright date of 2007. I know the number on the bag doesn't matter but I noticed the copyright date might help narrow it down a bit.

I've also included a picture of the set laid out so you can see which pieces are in it.

[image]

Comment: Regarding the copyright date, in this case the date makes no difference because the Dimensions series has only been around since 2015 but I appreciate the fact you have included it as it can sometimes be very helpful in identifying a set. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the [Trans-Yellow Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Tooth Horizontal](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=49668&colorID=19&in=A)

which appears only in three sets this is:

[71264-1: The LEGO Batman Movie: Play the Complete Movie](https://brickset.com/sets/71264-1/The-LEGO-Batman-Movie-Play-the-Complete-Movie)
[image]